# For each partition in query, do a case select

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, partitioning, row-number

On the following query result coming from a CTE:

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
|  STORE  |   DATE   |   TIME   | RESPONSE | ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Store 1 | 11/15/19 | 15:37:40 |     1    |          1          |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Store 1 | 11/15/19 | 15:37:40 |     1    |          2          |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Store 1 | 11/15/19 | 16:55:12 |     2    |          3          |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Store 1 | 11/15/19 | 16:55:12 |     2    |          4          |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I've been trying to find out if there's any way to display on my query results on one single store:

- if response 1 and 2 exist for the store, I want to only display response 1 on the results
- if only response 1 exists for the store, display nothing.
- if only response 2 exists for the store, display response 2.

I have a large amount of stores on my table of course,  and I'm aware this may be achieved through a case statement, but the table from this query is not originally partitioned, and I tried to add a row_number() function with partition by the "store" column and wrap my query in a CTE to be able to query the row number function, but it seems I'm just not getting anywhere with it. So I was wondering if there could be any other way to run a query like this on each row group.

**EDIT:**

Here's a simplified version of my CTE. Not posting the original since it's rather a large query with lots of joins:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
        STORE_ID,
        STORE,
        CONVERT (varchar, INPUT_DATE, 103) AS DATE,
        TIME, 
        RESPONSE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STORE ORDER BY STORE) AS STORE


FROM TABLE_1

WHERE   INPUT_DATE BETWEEN 2019-11-15 AND 2019-11-15

)

SELECT *

FROM CTE
```

Comment: The dataset that your CTE returns has duplicate records already. You might be better off showing us your CTE to start with (or a simplified version of it).

Comment: @GMB I updated the question. my original query is quite large and has several inner joins, what I posted anyway I believe should work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest using window functions, but like this:

```
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             sum(case when response = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by store) as response_1,
             sum(case when response = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by store) as response_2
      from cte 
      where response in (1, 2)
     ) cte
where response_2 > 0 and
      (response_1 > 0 and response = 1 or
       response_1 = 0 and response = 2
      );
```

Comment: I'm testing this solution right now. Just a question , I've never seen the syntax SELECT whatever .*   -  In this scenario, what does it mean?

Comment: @HectorSoto . . . It means:  "select all the columns that the table alias refers to".

Answer (score 0):

What about the following using `OUTER APPLY()`

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (STORE INT,DT DATE, TIME time(3), RESPONSE INT, ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE INT)


INSERT INTO @Tab
VALUES 
(1,'11/15/19','15:37:40',1,1),
(1,'11/15/19','15:37:40',1,2),
(1,'11/15/19','16:55:12',2,3),
(1,'11/15/19','16:55:12',2,4),
(2,'11/15/19','16:55:12',2,1),
(2,'11/15/19','16:55:12',2,2),
(3,'11/15/19','16:55:12',1,1),
(3,'11/15/19','16:55:12',1,2)


SELECT t.Store
     , t.Dt
     , t.Time
     , CASE WHEN tt.DistinctResponse = 3 THEN 1
            WHEN tt.DistinctResponse = 2 THEN 2
            ELSE NULL END AS Response
     , t.Row_Number_By_Store
FROM @Tab t
OUTER APPLY(
            SELECT t2.Store, SUM(DISTINCT t2.Response) AS DistinctResponse
            FROM @Tab t2
            WHERE t2.Store = t.Store
            GROUP BY t2.Store
           ) tt
```

Comment: please pardon my ignorance, so would @tab be like a temporary table?

Comment: Yes - technically a table variable. You can replace that with the name of your CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that also starts from a CTE.

It uses the window versions of MIN & MAX.
And a trick with a modulus to calculate a flag.

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS
> (
>   SELECT 
>     STORE
>   , CAST(dt AS DATE) AS [DATE]
>   , CAST(dt AS TIME) AS [TIME] 
>   , RESPONSE
>   , ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE
>   FROM (VALUES
>   ('Store1','2019-11-15 15:37:40',1,1),
>   ('Store1','2019-11-15 15:37:40',1,2),
>   ('Store1','2019-11-15 16:55:12',2,3),
>   ('Store1','2019-11-15 15:37:12',2,4),
>   ('Store2','2019-11-16 15:37:40',1,1),
>   ('Store2','2019-11-16 15:37:40',1,2),
>   ('Store3','2019-11-17 16:55:12',2,3),
>   ('Store3','2019-11-17 15:37:12',2,4)
>   ) v(STORE, dt, RESPONSE, ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE)
> )
> , CTE_DATA2 AS
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , CAST(IIF((
>       RESPONSE
>     + MIN(RESPONSE) 
>       OVER (PARTITION BY STORE, [DATE]) 
>     + MAX(RESPONSE) 
>       OVER (PARTITION BY STORE, [DATE]))%2 = 1, 0, 1
>     ) AS BIT) AS Flag
>   FROM CTE_DATA
> )
> SELECT STORE, [DATE], [TIME], RESPONSE, ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE
> FROM CTE_DATA2
> WHERE Flag = 1
> ORDER BY STORE, [DATE], ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> STORE  | DATE                | TIME     | RESPONSE | ROW_NUMBER_BY_STORE
> :----- | :------------------ | :------- | -------: | ------------------:
> Store1 | 15/11/2019 00:00:00 | 15:37:40 |        1 |                   1
> Store1 | 15/11/2019 00:00:00 | 15:37:40 |        1 |                   2
> Store3 | 17/11/2019 00:00:00 | 16:55:12 |        2 |                   3
> Store3 | 17/11/2019 00:00:00 | 15:37:12 |        2 |                   4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e8e8b333c5ef87905f46c963617e49ee)*